# How can I reference a workbook within another workbook to automatically open the file?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains command buttons to run the macro. I want the file path for Workbook 3 to be saved in the worksheet underneath the command button in cell B17. I want the macro below to reference that cell and automatically open Workbook 3. The file path will change everyday and I do not want to have to change it in the developer tab. Please help!

```
Sub NCFinal()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim Wb3 As Workbook

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("A:Desktop\Excel Files\Data Template.xlsb")
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("A:Desktop\Excel Files\MarchData.xlsb")
**Set Wb3 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B17").Value)**
Wb1.Sheets("FRD").Copy After:=Wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Wb3.Sheets("CDGL Data").Copy After:=Wb2.Sheets("FRD")

Wb1.Close False
Wb3.Close False
```

Comment: Which workbook/worksheet do you want the file path to be saved in (cell B17) ?  You could do something like wb1.sheets('sheetname').cells(17,2) = wb3.FullName

Comment: Your starred line looks like it should work. What is the problem exactly? What happens when you run this? Do you get an error, or does something else unexpected happen?

Comment: I get an error @ChrisMelville..the file path that I want to open is located in another workbook that I open manually to hit the command buttons

Comment: @CodyG. I want Workbook 3 to open the file path located in B17 in a workbook that contains the command buttons already (which I open manually)

Comment: Try Tim William's Code. ThisWorkbook may be necessary because when you use the .Open command the 'active workbook' changes to MarchData, therefore when you run Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B17").Value it tries to pull MarchData.xlsb's B17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set Wb3 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B17").Value)
```