# Save a workbook with file path referenced in cell

Tags: vba, excel

What is the correct code in order for the workbook to save to the referenced file path in cell B19? The file path looks like this C:Desktop\ExcelFiles\Data Table.xlsb

```
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B19").Value
'^^^Need help understanding the correct syntax of this line ^^^
```

Comment: This looks good, but you might need to supply the `FileFormat` argument as well, for `.xlsb`. See [`SaveAs Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) for more. Also, add `ThisWorkbook` in front of `Sheets` in the `Filename` argument.

Comment: You should know the answer from your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929284/how-can-i-reference-a-workbook-within-another-workbook-to-automatically-open-the). Also, `C:` needs a slash.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Where would I need to reference the Filetype?

Comment: @Hags - That is why I provided you the link, to learn more about it.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you for the help but still not understanding based on the link...

Comment: @Hags - Did you actually try any of the other suggestions given to you in the comments? From myself or from findwindow

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes I did, but still am having trouble

Comment: @hags - do a `debug.print` on `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B19").Value` and post your results

Comment: No error comes up and the file does not save...I am having trouble with where to identify the file type. @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @hags - `50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think I am not understanding what you are saying to do...can you include the code below?

Comment: `Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B19").Value, FileFormat:=50` -> *but this all depends on the text in `Range("B19")` being a **valid file path***.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Sub SaveMe()

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B19").Value, _
        FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Basically,just turn on the Macro Recorder and modify the code, slightly, to suit your needs.